# What could cause xmlrpclib.ServerProxy to send headers only?

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I am using Python 2.6.4 built-in xmlrpclib.ServerProxy. On the server side, and every now and then, the server will only get the headers of the request. I've worked around it by using transport that buffers the whole request before sending it, but I have no idea what could cause such behavior.

Comment: Are you sure client sent every thing out?

Comment: @PasteBT ServerProxy uses httplib which does separate sends for the request line, the header and the content. But none of the sends return error. I am not sure how else to check if everything was sent.